# Semantic UI - navigating to external link using Icon element

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I'm using the latest versions of `react` and `semantic-ui-react`

I have this `Icon`element set up from semantic implementing navigation to an external link (github)

```
        <Menu.Item
          position="right"
          to="https://github.com"
          as={Link}
        >
          <Icon name="github" size="big" />
        </Menu.Item>
```

When I click the icon in my UI, it's trying to append the github url to the url of my UI. So I'm at `localhost:blah/someUrl` it's requesting `localhost:blah/someUrl/https://github.com`

Is this an issue with routing or misuse of the `<Icon>` props?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's rather a misuse of router link: If you want to link to external pages, don't use routers `<Link>` component.

It will work the following way:

```
<Menu.Item
 href="https://github.com"
 position="right"
 target="_blank"
>
 <Icon name="github" size="big" />
</Menu.Item>
```

Comment: ah yeah, I knew href was the answer